# How to custom sort then sub-sort in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets say I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
        {
            name: 'test1',
            status: 'pending',
            date: 'Jan 17 2017 21:00:23'
        },
        {
            name: 'test2',
            status: 'pending',
            date: 'Jan 14 2017 21:00:23'
        },
        {
            name: 'test3',
            status: 'active',
            date: 'Jan 10 2017 21:00:23'
        }
    ];
```

I first want to sort it based on "status" where all the items with "pending" substatus should come before "active". (I've other statuses as well so orderBy Name DESC won't work.)

Later I want to subsort them based on date descending.

In my angular script I have a variable defined as sortField:

```
$scope.sortField = ['status', '-date'];
```

(doesn't work because Active gets sorted before Pending does)

And I have this in my html:

```
<li ng-repeat="form in forms | orderBy:sortField:isAsc " class="row {{Contextual}}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
    ...
</li>
```

I have been trying to search online but couldn't get anywhere. How do you custom sort one field "status" and normal sort the other one "date"?

Comment: use a minus before status i.e `$scope.sortField = ['-status', '-date']; `

Comment: @Ladmerc won't work because I have other statuses too and Pending is not the last one. I also have Postponed as one of the status.

Comment: I see, so irrespective of the others, pending should always be first?

Answer (score 0):

The `orderBy` filter uses an expression to compute the order. You can pass a string or function as the expression. Additionally, you can pass an array as the expression and your array can contain strings/function predicates.

That said, you can define your custom sort function and pass in the array:

```
<li ng-repeat="form in forms | orderBy: [statusOrder, '-date']">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.statusOrder = function(item) {
   if (item.status === 'pending') {
     return 1; // smaller value means this should be placed first
   } else {
      return 2; // all other statuses not 'pending' should be returned as is
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the date order not correct, Angular sorts the date alphabetically since the date is a string. You have two options:

1. Update your array source so the date string becomes a date object. This is more performant $scope wise.

   `angular.forEach($scope.array, function(item) {
      item.date = new Date(item.date)
   })`
2. Create a custom dateSort function as you did for the status. The function should simply `return new Date(item.date)`

Updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/51bsbzL0/258/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ladmerc. I see that status order is working fine. But the dates inside are not getting sorted w.r.t the status group.